# How to add 1 hour to 8601 format time string in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, string, windows, time, iso8601

I've got an 8601 format time string like so:

std::string strTime("1601-01-01T00:01:53.537Z");

I want to increment the hour and change its value to

"1601-01-01T01:01:53.537Z"

I think the steps are: convert string to a time object, increment the hour by 1, convert the object back to a string.

Of course, it would be helpful if all the normal time considerations and boundaries were taken into account (such as adding an hour to 11:30 pm will move to the next day, etc...). I've been looking at strftime, strptime, std::get_time and others but have not been able to work it out yet.

I'm using VS2012 on Windows. Thanks.

Comment: So keep researching until you find the library functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code to get you started.

```
char *AddHour(char *dest, size_t size, const char *timestamp) {
  Initialize struct tm
  Scan timestamp into tm
  Check scanning success
  Check year range validity
  Bring into range acceptable by mktime()
  Add hour
  Call mktime()
  Undo range adjustment made beforehand
  Print tm to dest
  return dest;
}
```

Even though `mktime()` uses local timezone, by keeping the `tm_isdst == 0` we can use this for the Z timezone (UTC) for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply scan the string into various parts.  Add 1 hour and then reform the string

```
  string --> struct tm tm;

  // Add hour
  if (++tm.tm_hour >= 24) {
    tm.tm_hour = 0;
    if (++tm.tm_mday > EOM(tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon)) {
      tm.tm_mday = 1;
      if (++tm.tm_mon > 12) {
        tm.tm_mon = 1;
        tm.tm_year++;
      }
    }
  }

  struct tm tm --> string
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a C library that parses and formats a ISO 8601 calendar date with time and zone designator in extended format. It's available on Github, [c-timestamp](https://github.com/chansen/c-timestamp).

```
{
    timestamp_t ts;
    char *str = "1601-01-01T00:01:53.537Z";

    timestamp_parse(str, strlen(str), &ts);
    ts.sec += 1*60*60;
    timestamp_format(str, strlen(str), &ts);
    puts(str);
}
```